# Add term list as class

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to add a list of terms as a class for custom post types.

```
<?php while($portfolio->have_posts()) : $portfolio->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php $categories = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'project_type');
                        foreach($categories as $category){

                            return $category->name;
                        }
                    ?> 


                    <div class='portfolio-tile <?php echo $category ;?>'>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium' ); ?>

                    </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                </div>

        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the best way to handle this problem was to leverage the post_class function and add the loop through the function.php file. this is the code in the function.php file:

```
function term_class($classes){

global $post;

$taxonomies = array('project_type');
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , $taxonomies);

 foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $classes[] = $term->name;
 }

 return $classes;

}

add_filter( 'post_class', 'term_class' );
add_filter( 'body_class', 'term_class' );
```

Then I just added the post_class() function the custom posts template. Thanks for all the help everyone.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `return` then your loop will not work properly. You can try the code this way:

```
<?php while($portfolio->have_posts()) : $portfolio->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php $term_class = ''; 
                        $categories = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'project_type');
                        foreach($categories as $category){

                            $term_class .= ' ' . $category->name;
                        }
                    ?> 


                    <div class='portfolio-tile <?php echo trim($term_class) ;?>'>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium' ); ?>

                    </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                </div>

        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: I'm getting a all the terms form the terms list and the increment by 1 with each div.

Comment: I did not understand your question. Can you explain more?

Comment: Each custom post type will have 2-3 terms associated with it. I need to get those terms added to each posts class. Thanks for you help.

Comment: foreach for terms is not working properly? i think that it is adding multiple terms and loop is working perfectly